# Is there a way to complete Small Time Delivery without spending Credits?

Tags: cross-code

Because it seems that even though [Spice and Fruit Sets](https://crosscode.fandom.com/wiki/Items/Trade) say "**Mostly** obtained from traders", emphasis mine, actually, they're the *only* way to obtain them?

Am I correct?